# benchmarking python (command line)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, benchmarking

I have a program in python 3.6 that I made to run in linux. I needed to know how much cpu, memory, etc., it consumed when it was executed (in command line), could you help me?

Thank you

Note: Sorry for the tags used, I was not sure which ones to put

Answer (score 1):

For basic experiments you can use `%timeit` with the `ipython` interpreter. For high precision low level ones - `perf`. For everything in between there is an article specifically on the topic in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).

Comment: "perf" show cpu, memory, etc? Could you show an example?

Comment: @DiegoCardoso - it's a powerful profiler for linux, it wouldn't show python stack traces, only the native ones. The best tutorial I've come across is http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Answer (score 0):

For timing single lines, you can python's magic function `%timeit`. (You can also time multiple lines, however it would give result for complete execution and not per statement basis)

However for a detailed description, you can use cProfile. You can read the description [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).

Sample code that might help you:

[sample.py]

```
import time
print('Hello!')
time.sleep(2)
print('Thanks for waiting!')
```

cProfile can help you profile your program written in sample.py. Run your python file like below from your linux terminal.

```
user@this-pc$ python3 -m cProfile sample.py
```

Output:

```
Hello!
Thanks for waiting!
         6 function calls in 2.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.001    2.001 sample.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.001    2.001 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    2.001    2.001    2.001    2.001 {built-in method time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It helped a lot.
But one last time, where do I see cpu consumption and memory in the example?

Comment: I am not sure if memory consumption per statement is possible in cProfiler. Maybe you can check this: https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/

Comment: Ok, i'll take a look. What about cpu consumption?
thank you so much again

Comment: CPU consumption as in? You want number of CPU cycles? cProfile displays you amount of time spent per call per statement.